# Jenkins doesn't detect my VS19 installation, even though MSBuild.exe exists

Tags: c++, visual-studio, jenkins, cmake, msbuild

I'm trying to build a VS19 project using CMake in a Jenkins pipeline. I had some issues with installing CMake, but after explicitly EXPORTing it to the PATH (as opposed to using the `--installargs` flag, I was able to get past that.)
Now, I've installed visualstudio19buildtools (and later visualstudio19community), in order to get the command `cmake -g "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A "x64" -S . -B out` to work. But everytime I get the error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (project):
  Generator

    Visual Studio 16 2019

  could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
```

I know that `MSBuild.exe` is present, because in my pipeline I checked before trying to run the cmake command above.  I'm super confused and not sure what to try next. Any suggestions appreciated, thanks.

```
+ ls 'C:\VS2019\MSBuild\Current\Bin'
1028
1031
1033
1036
1040
1041
1042
1049
2052
3082
AssemblyFolders.config
FileTracker32.dll
FileTracker64.dll
MSBuild
MSBuild.exe
MSBuild.exe.config
........
```

Comment: There seems to be an open issue for this in the CMake repo:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22082

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't seen this I'll take a look, thanks